# How to group_by this array of hashs (Enumerable) [Ruby, Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, group-by, enumerable

I have an array (@items) of hashs with this structure:

@items:

```
{'item' => item, 'stickers' => stickers}
...
```

And the `item` is an ActiveRecord with the attr I want to group_by: `csgo_type`.

My code:

```
<% @items.group_by { |d| d['item'][:csgo_type] }.each do |a| %>
    <%= render partial: 'item', locals: {a: a} %>
<% end %>
```

But this doesnt group at all.

I'm looking for a result like this:

`[ { :csgo_type => #ActiveRecord(csgo_type 1), :items => [array of some @items of this type] }, {...} ...]`

Comment: It's excellent that you found a solution to your problem... bravo!  At SO, we encourage you answer your own question, but it's better if you add it below using the "Your Answer" box rather than editing it into your question.  Would you consider editing your question to remove the answer and adding it back using the "Your Answer" box below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
<% @items.group_by { |d| d['item'].csgo_type }.each do |a,b| %>
    === <%= a.name %>
    <% b.each do |cada| %>
        <%= render partial: 'item', locals: {cada: cada, i: 1} %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```